# How can I use SQL to find events with overlapping durations?

Tags: sql, mysql-5.7

I have the following table

| Field | Type | Null | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EventId | int(11) | NO | PRI |
| Duration | int(11) | NO |  |
| EventParentId | int(11) | NO | MUL |
| EventDateTime | datetime | NO | PRI |
| Created | datetime | NO |  |
| est_datetime | datetime | YES | MUL |
| pacific_ts | int(11) | YES | MUL |
| eastern_ts | int(11) | YES | MUL |
| updated | datetime | YES |  |

Edit: I need to find all of the unique `EventParentId` of any column that would have an overlap. `eastern_ts` and `pacific_ts` would be the start time and each event also has a `duration` in seconds. I am newer to SQL and not sure how this would need to be done. Would it be easier to just grab all columns and filter using Java or is this possible with only SQL?

| EventId | Duration | EventParentId | EventDateTime | pacific_ts | eastern_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 30 | 56789 | 2023-03-01T10:00:00 | 1677693600 | 1677704400 |
| 1235 | 45 | 98765 | 2023-03-01T10:01:00 | 167769366 | NULL |
| 1236 | 45 | 98765 | 2023-03-01T10:01:15 | 1677693675 | NULL |
| 4567 | 60 | 34567 | 2023-03-03T09:45:20 | NULL | 1677865520 |
| 4568 | 45 | 34567 | 2023-03-03T09:45:40 | NULL | 1677865540 |
| 2345 | 60 | 65432 | 2023-03-03T09:45:40 | 1677854740 | 1677865540 |

Because `1235` and `1236` share an `EventParentId` and have overlapping duration I would expect `EventParentId` 98765.  I would also expect `EventParentId` `34567` because `4567` and `4568` have overlapping durations, but would not expect `65432` because it does not overlap anything within the same `EventParentId`

Edit: Expected result

| EventId | Duration | EventParentId | EventDateTime | pacific_ts | eastern_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1235 | 45 | 98765 | 2023-03-01T10:01:00 | 167769366 | NULL |
| 4567 | 60 | 34567 | 2023-03-03T09:45:20 | NULL | 1677865520 |

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result (using the same table format), i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: And also add a tag for the dbms you're using. (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: A timestamp refers to a specific instant. How can one instant overlap another? A start to end **range** could overlap, but not a single timestamp.

Comment: try to group by EventParentId HAVING Count(*) > 1 -> it will provide a groups where EventParentId matched more than once, then you can add where condition to remove not "overlaped" records. P.S. i think overlaping belongs to ranges not to single timestamps. please advice...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  your_table  AS a
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM your_table   AS b
     WHERE b.EventParentId  = a.EventParentId
       AND b.EventID       <> a.EventID
       AND b.EventDateTime >= a.EventDateTime
       AND b.EventDateTime <  a.EventDateTime + INTERVAL a.Duration SECOND
  )
```